# Typescript fails to infer key-value pairs from lookup

Tags: typescript, record, lookup-tables, inference, keyof

In the below example I try to map to a list of InnerNamed typed values from a lookup of typed values, (see InnerNamed definition) but the inferred type is way too broad.

In the end, the type of `resolved` should be `(InnerNamed<"Cefn", 3> | InnerNamed<"Joe", "hey">)[]` equivalent to `({Cefn:3} | {Joe:"hey"})[]`. It is instead inferred as `InnerNamed<string, unknown>[]`

Is there anything I can do to improve inference here?

See also the [playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wobram) to experiment interactively.

````
/** Assert type of Object.entries */
type InferEntry<Lookup, K extends keyof Lookup = keyof Lookup> = {
  [K in keyof Lookup]: [K, Lookup[K]];
}[K];

/** Type for an object containing a single, named entry (common paradigm for javascript records like
 * ```
 * {
 *  MyItem:{some:"value"}
 * }
 * ```
 */
type InnerNamed<InnerName extends string, T> = { [k in InnerName]: T };
const namedProps: InnerNamed<"Cefn", {hi:number}> = {
  // autocompletes correctly
  Cefn: {
    hi: 3
  }
};

/** Map to InnerNamed types given a lookup of named types. */

type Resolved<Name extends string, Resolver extends Record<Name, any>> = {
  [N in Name]: InnerNamed<Name, Resolver[Name]>;
}[Name];

function createResolved<Name extends string, Resolver extends Record<Name, any>>(resolver:Resolver){
  return Object.entries(resolver).map((entry) => {
    const [name, value] = entry as InferEntry<typeof resolver>
    return {
      [name]:value
    }
  }) as Resolved<Name, Resolver>[]
}

// the type of resolved should be (InnerNamed<"Cefn", 3> | InnerNamed<"Joe", "hey">)[]
// i.e. ({Cefn:3} | {Joe:"hey"})[] 
// but is instead InnerNamed<string, unknown>[]
const resolved = createResolved({
  Cefn:3,
  Joe:"hey"
});


// printing out the actual structure of resolved
// shows the narrower type would be satisfied
// even though it was not inferred
console.log({resolved})
//   "resolved": [
//     {
//       "Cefn": 3
//     },
//     {
//       "Joe": "hey"
//     }
//   ]
// }
````

Comment: Does this question depend on knowledge of zod?  If so it's probably more important to tag with zod then with, say, "lookup-tables".  If not, could you [edit] the example to not refer to it?

Comment: The question doesn't rely on zod, but the motivation (and hence the things which are up for grabs to change) are constrained by the zod case. In the long run I need to be able to transform a structure (pseudo-code) like `{Aragorn:schema<A>,Bilbo:schema<B>, }` to `schema<({Aragorn:A} | {Bilbo:B})[]>` and this is one stage of the inference which doesn't complete correctly. I'll see if I can refactor to remove zod from the example, and hence state more clearly the kind of inference which is failing, hoping that suggested solutions are still compatible with the target case.

Comment: I have updated the example to remove zod but hopefully the original constraint I need to meet is still clear, even without the motivating example.

Comment: I'm only really going to be able to interact with the example code that's there, so if you have some toy/candidate `Schema` you'd like to put in there I'd be happy to look at it.  Given the code that *is* there I'd just write it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqprkN), but I don't know if it's stripped down more than is useful for you.  In any case you almost certainly don't want to use two type parameters for a single function parameter.  If my suggestion works for you I'll write it up as an answer; otherwise I'll watch to see if there's an [edit] that puts back some motivation.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. That's a valuable and direct answer which was able to start me on the right track. The alternative (without the two type parameters) and using Immer's `Immutable<T>` also gave me a solution for my real case, allowing inference from one structure to the other.